# Организация ввода списка

Tags: c++, ввод, std-list

Программа не работает, как правильно организовать ввод списка в программу.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    list<int> t;
    list<int> out;
    list<int> out2;

    int n;
    cin >> n;   // сколько нужно ввести элементов в последовательность 

    for (auto iter = t.begin(); n != 0; --n)
    {
        cout << *iter << ' ';            // здесь должен быть ввод
        iter++;
    }

    auto riter = t.rbegin();
    auto fiter = t.begin();

    while (riter != t.rend())
    {
        if (*riter < 0)
        {
            out.push_front(*riter);
        }

        if (*fiter >= 0)
        {
            out.push_back(*fiter);
        }
        riter++; fiter++;
    }

    for (auto iter = out.begin(); iter != out.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter << ' ';
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Лучше скажите, что вы собираетесь сделать в программе.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам уже известно кол-во элементов для ввода, т.е. пользователь ввёл `n`, то достаточно просто выполнить цикл вида:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    int e;
    cin >> e; 
    t.push_back(e);
}
```